# Finding the rotation based on quaternion rotation

Tags: 3d, rotations, quaternions, spherical-coordinates, project-euler

I have a problem with computer vision-related task that I'm struggling with.

So in short I have images based on  4 set of cameras that takes 360 degrees images but the issue is that those cameras are outputting rotated images.
Camera 0 output images that are rotated +90 degree clockwise

ex: [image]

Camera 1->3 output images that are rotated -90 degrees clockwise.

ex:[image]

Every camera have quaternion as follows:

```
       Cam 0          Cam 1          Cam 2          Cam 3
W       0.554038881   0.7933533473    0.5663966889   0.001525752367
X      -0.436331528   0               0.4305736222  -0.6145368421
Y      -0.4300295689  0.6087614198    0.4262777488  -0.001479600449
Z      -0.5636756921  0              -0.5586487515   0.7888852594
```

Is there any mathematical method where I can predict by quaternion if the image is rotated to 90 degrees on the left or to the right?

the motive behind finding this is that those images are passed to an Object detection deep learning model. Any object detection model is trained on a large dataset of images that are correctly oriented so when I try to detect assets in a rotated image the model cannot detect due to its limitation in extracting features from rotated images because it is not trained on.

My approach is to rotate those images and then pass them to the detection model because when Images are not rotated the OB model detects assets but once the image is rotated +- 90 it fails in detecting any assets.

Additionally, I know that all images are rotated 90 degrees but what I'm missing is the direction (+90 or -90 clockwise) so If I rotate the image by +90 degrees some images might have correct rotation while others will be rotated 180 degrees which returns me to the original problem.

**PS**: sending 2 copies of the same image rotated -+90 is not feasible in my application due to limitation in processing power and time wich will lead to O(2n) instead of O(n)

Comment: What difference is it to you if it is one way or another? If if makes no real difference then there is no problem. If it does make a difference, in what way? And if so, and you can tell by the difference it makes, then it is not by any mathematical method. In other words, you need to tell us much more details about your setup and purpose.

Comment: Those images are passed to an Object detection deep learning model. Any object detection model is trained on a large dataset of images that are correctly oriented so when I try to detect assets in a rotated image the model cannot detect due to its limitation in extracting features from rotated images because it is not trained on. My approach is to rotate those images and then pass them to the detection model because when Images are not rotated the OB model detect assets but once the image is rotated +- 90 it fails in detecting any assets.

Comment: Additionally, I know that all images are rotated 90 degrees but what I'm missing is the direction (+90 or -90 clockwise) so If I rotate the image +90 degree some images might  have correct rotation while others will be rotated 180 degrees which returns me to the original problem

Comment: All those details should be edited into the body of your question. Comments can be easily deleted or ignored. Please do the edits. I still don't see the problem. You are  passing the images to a detection algorithm. Why not try both +90 and -90 orientations and see if they are detected? Please include the explanation in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I added the more detailed description into the question itself, returning to your question, sending 2 copies of each image is the last resort especially if I can find the correct rotation in a programmatic way using an algorithm. Also, sending 2 copies of the same image can be time-consuming especially when working on a dataset with thousands of images each taking 5-6 sec to process.